# UDP - Multithreaded server is unable to distinguish between an ack msg and a connection msg

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, udp, pthreads

I am trying to implement a multithreaded UDP server where each thread services one client. 
So far, the clients are being registered correctly and the data is being received by the clients. In order to make it reliable, i tried sending a negative acknowledgement when the message was not received within a particular time interval.

This acknowledgement is being treated as a request from a new client in the server side recvfrom() function. How do i distinguish the two at the server side? Are there any functions related to send and receive that can do the same?

The code is in c and i have used pthreads to implement the threading function.I have used the basic sendto() and recvfrom() socket functions to implement the same.

Code outline:

```
At the server side:

recvfrom()
when received:
Add to client list
create thread:
send data in the thread function
exit thread

At the client side:

sendto()  -> to initiate the request to the server
when time < timeout
recvfrom() -> receive the data from the server
when timeout occurs
sendto()   -> send negative acknowledgement.
```

Comment: Put a command code at the front of your UDP data that indicates what sort of message it is.  One byte would probably be sufficient.

Comment: How would i be able to distinguish the same at the server side? Using the length of the message received from the client?

Comment: If you want a reliable, connection-oriented datagram protocol, you have two choices. Add a datagram layer to TCP, or try to add reliability and connections to UDP. The first choice is much easier.

Comment: Which side , server or client, the negative acknouwledgement may be sent from?  UDP is unreliable communication, so packet may be lost. When first packet is lost, client knows nothing and cannot do anything. In same way, server cannot know first packet reached to client or not, so server can do nothing.  Your system  needs some mechanism of acknowledgement.

Comment: The issue is, when I am trying to implement a mechanism of acknowledgement, the acknowledged message is being interpreted as a new client request. The acknowledge message isn't reaching the corresponding server thread that is servicing that particular client.

Comment: @Networks101 in that case, your protocol on top of UDP is unfit for purpose.  You need to redesign it.

Comment: UDP just delivers bytes to you. Any interpretation of bytes is up to you. Your server and your client need to agree on what is the difference between bytes for NAK and bytes for connection request.

Answer (score 0):

`recvfrom()` will fill out a socket address structure of the correct type with the address of the client.

You could maintain a data structure that maps client addresses (including the port number) to threads.  You can then use this to pass subsequent messages from the client to the correct thread.